# Can the brakes of a Semi-trailer truck overcome the torque of the engine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, torque, power

On the average Semi-trailer truck, assuming an average load, can the engine overcome the brakes and continue spinning the wheels despite the operator applying the brakes fully?

This would be assuming the brakes are in good operating condition, and are not overheated or failing in some way.

Additionally, would this also be the case if the tractor unit had no trailer on it, and no weight? How about fully loaded?

Comment: Could you please improve your question by providing values? We are not a search engine, I am definitely not going to search for those values. The easy way to answer your question is by giving the torque output of the truck vs the max torque brakes can handle. However inclination of road, load, etc all will affect the answer. Lastly, ABS was invented for a reason and brakes should never lock wheels indefinitely.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have those values. I searched for them, but I couldn't find them. I was hoping that either someone would know, or we could interpolate them from other statistics about trucks.

Comment: This question doesn't really belong on this site.  As already mentioned, it's just a matter of comparing the engine specs to the brake specs.  You should look for a trucking forum.

Comment: I'm looking for a scientific explanation, with a break down of the math. There are many other similar questions on the site that have gotten responses, so I don't understand how mine is an issue.

Comment: There is the engineeringSE (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/), you should give that a try, maybe someone from the automotive industry is there. And I doubt that a question with the like of yours had been answered.

Comment: @nabeelr:  I recommend you modify your question based on the fact that you want a "break down of the math".  It would still be better suited to the engineering site in my opinion.  Basicially, to calculate the answer to your question, you would need to compare the engine torque to the brake torque.  Brake torque can be calculated using: brake pressure, total area of all the brake pistons, and the average distance from the wheel centerline to the piston radius.

Comment: @nabeelr:  In my previous comment, I forgot to mention that you would also need to know the coefficient of friction between the brake pads and rotors.

Answer (score 2):

Rob is right. Note that it's common to rate the braking power of a vehicle brake in *horsepower* (maximum brake torque times wheel RPM) and the total braking horsepower will be many time greater than the horsepower rating of the engine in that same vehicle.

This allows the brakes in the vehicle, when slammed fully on, to decelerate the vehicle far faster than the engine could accelerate it to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

One step in a commercial vehicle pre-trip inspection (at least, on vehicles with automatic transmissions) is to apply the parking brake, put the vehicle in drive, and rev the engine. If the brake doesn’t hold the vehicle in place, the vehicle is not safe to drive.

This is mostly about being able to park the vehicle safely on inclines, so one does not generally apply full throttle. But it’s a partial answer: there *must* exist a substantial parameter space where the brakes are stronger than the engine in its lowest gear.

Comment: This is true of passenger vehicles as well - the brakes can always overcome the engine to stop the vehicle.

Comment: One might note that the question also asks about a vehicle with a trailer — but a functioning trailer has its own brakes.